# How can I replace text after a specific word using sed instead of changing the whole line?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I am trying to replace text after a specific word but `sed` is changing the whole line. Extract one word after a specific word

Input file: **sample.txt**

```
My Hostname:internal is valid.
some log file entries
some log file entries
```

Output:

```
My Hostname:mmphate
some log file entries
some log file entries
```

Expected output:

```
My Hostname:mmphate is valid.
some log file entries
some log file entries
```

I have written the below script which is changing all the words after `Hostname:` I want to change only one word after `Hostname:`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

HOST=$(curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname)
while getopts ih opt
do
  case $opt in
  i)
    ;;
  h)
    sed -e "s/Hostname:.*/Hostname:$HOST/g" sample.txt
    echo "Updated Hostname: $HOST"
    ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: if you want to change only that specific word, use that `'s/Hostname:internal/Hostname:mmphate/'` .. `.*` will match everything after `Hostname:`

Comment: i want to change word after Hostname:   . not specific word like internal

Comment: then add that detail to question and change example to show two or more different words to change

Comment: i have added question in detail

Comment: define word.. does it have only alphabets? both lower/upper case? is it always followed by space? depending on that, you can use various ways.. `"s/Hostname:[^ ]*/Hostname:$HOST/g"` is one

Comment: this may work : sed -i 's/:[A-Za-z]*/:$HOST/' g

Comment: @Rakesh.N With `'` instead of `"` this won't work as `$HOST` will not get expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.*` matches everything in the rest of the line, so everything is replaced. If you want to replace everything upto the next space then you need `[^ ] instead of`.`

Answer (score 1):

When you perform double quote interpolations on the ***rhs*** of `s///` you need to be aware of escaping proplery the inputs, for they may be special to `sed` and hence result in an error or even worse, no errors, but a result that was totally unintended. Consider, e.g, what would happen if your `$HOST` comprised an ampersand `&` or a `/`.

```
# definitions
TAB=`echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\011'`; # tab
SPC=`echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\040'`; # space
eval "`echo 'n=qsq' | tr 'qs' '\047\012'`"; # newline

# construct regexes
s="[$SPC$TAB]";  # spc/tab regex
S="[^$SPC$TAB]"; # nonwhitespace regex

# perform the escape operation
esc() {
   set -- "${1//\\/\\\\}" # escape backslash to prevent it from dissolving
   set -- "${1//\//\\\/}" # escape forward slash to prevent from clashing with delimiters
   set -- "${1//&/\\&}"   # escape ampersand since it has a specific meaning rhs of s//
   set -- "${1//\"/\\\"}" # escape double quotes in an interpolation
   set -- "${1//$n/\\$n}" # escape newlines
   printf '%s\n' "$@"
}

# grab the hostname
HOST=$(curl -s 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname)

# escape hostname to enable it to be used seamlessly on the rhs of s///
host_esc=$(esc "$HOST")

# and then...
sed -e "s/\(${s}Hostname\):$S$S*/\1:$host_esc/g" sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not reproducable :

```
$ name="george"
$ echo "My Hostname:internal is valid." |sed "s/internal/$name/g"
My Hostname:george is valid.
```

In case the word `internal` exists also in the log entries bellow `My Hostname` then you can use something like this:

```
$ sed -r "s/(My Hostname:)(internal)/\1$name/g" file4
My Hostname:george is valid.
internal log entry
log internal entry
```

If you don't have `GNU Sed` or your `sed` does not work as expected for some reason, for such simple replacements you can always switch to `perl` which works with the same way everywhere:

```
$ cat file4
My Hostname:internal is valid.
internal log entry
log internal entry

$ perl -pe "s/(My Hostname:)(internal)/\1$name/g" file4
My Hostname:george is valid.
internal log entry
log internal entry
```

Both sed and perl can be combined with `-i` for in place editing if required.